# React & Handsontable - TypeError: Cannot read property 'ownerDocument' of null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, handsontable

I want to use the Handsontable but I'm failing. I followed the instructions in the docs and came up with following code.

**Report.js file**

```
export const Report = () => {

  const [data, setData] = useState([
    ["", "Ford", "Volvo", "Toyota", "Honda"],
    ["2016", 10, 11, 12, 13],
    ["2017", 20, 11, 14, 13],
    ["2018", 30, 15, 12, 13]
  ]);


const container = document.getElementById("reportTable"); 
console.log(container);
const Hot = new Handsontable(container, {
  data: data, 
  rowHeaders: true, 
  colHeaders: true, 
  filters: true, 
  dropdownMenu: true

})

const onChange = ()=>{
  setData([])
}


return (
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#fff", 
  <div className="main-container">

        <div className={styles.tableDiv}>
              <p className={styles.reportText}>Report Your Daily Progress</p> 
              <div id="reportTable"></div>
        </div>
  </div>
)
}
```

However, I'm getting this error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'ownerDocument' of null`
 and I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I'd appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: That library has React support out of the box; you should use it: https://handsontable.com/docs/7.1.1/frameworks-wrapper-for-react-simple-examples.html

Comment: @ChrisG, thanks for the recommendation. It worked.